# Controlling google tv from an installed app on the gtv itself

Tags: android, google-tv

I did some search to find more on how to do remote functions inside an app in the google tv itself. I am a beginner so i will sort out my question:

I want something like a local gtv-remote inside my app, i only want to do PIP for the TV at certain times, i found that you can do that through the remote, but why would i need the pairing for?

Thanks much

Answer (score 2):

You can't currently do that.  Sorry.  I'll talk with some of the engineers about this when they return from CES.

Comment: Thanks, could you please post whatever you find about that.